# Using sed to comment out lines that contain a specific string of text

Tags: sed

Please bear with me as I'm new to the forums and tried to do my research before posting this.  What I'm trying to do is to use `sed` to look through multiple lines of a file and any line that contains the words 'CPU Usage" I want it to comment out that line and also 19 lines immediately after that.

Example `file.txt`

```
This is some random text CPU USAGE more random text
Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5
etc.
```

I want `sed` to find the string of text CPU usage and comment out the line and the 19 lines following

```
#This is some random text CPU USAGE more random text
#Line2
#Line3
#Line4
#Line5
#etc.
```

This is what I've been trying but obviously it is not working since I'm posting on here asking for help

```
sed '/\/(CPU Usage)s/^/#/+18 > File_name
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unknown command: `^'
```

I'd like to be able to use this on multiple files. Any help you can provide is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

GNU `sed` has a non-standard extension (okay, it has many non-standard extensions, but there's one that's relevant here) of permitting [`/pattern/,+N`](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses) to mean from the line matching `pattern` to that line plus N.

I'm not quite sure what you expected your `sed` command to do with the `\/` part of the pattern, and you're missing a single quote in what you show, but this does the trick:

```
sed '/CPU Usage/,+19 s/^/#/'
```

If you want to overwrite the original files, add `-i .bak` (or just `-i` if you don't mind losing your originals).

If you don't have GNU `sed`, now might be a good time to install it.

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be done with `awk`

```
awk '/CPU Usage/ {f=20} f && f-- {$0="#"$0}1' file
```

When `CPU Usage` is found, set flag `f=20`
If flag  `f` is true, decrements until `0` and for every time, add `#` in front of the line and print it.

Answer (score 0):

Think this should work, cant test it, if anyone finds something wrong just let me know :)

```
awk '/CPU Usage/{t=1}t{x++;$0="#"$0}x==19{t=0;x=0}1' file
```